# Resetting authentification cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, identity

I have a log-in page and when authenticated users who return to this page after they've been authenticated I want them to reauthenticate themselves. For now, this is what I have:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        authenticationManager.SignOut();
    }
}
```

How can I clear the authentication cookie and set a new one? I'm using Identity authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete a cookie you set it's expiration date to sometime in the past. If you want to replace the cookie simply store a new cookie with the same name. [More about cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)